# I wants to Hide my .html extension while using the .html extension in my editor

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove the .html extension on my website, while using .html I my editor (dreamweaver.) I have looked at some of the other codes, but they all require me to delete my .html extension of my files. and when I do that dreamweaver won't give me a live view which I use a lot.

atm I use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's not possible I'm afraid. For the `.htaccess` code to work, you will need to remove the `.html` from the code. DW live isn't very good imo and I would advise you install MAMP. Very easy to use.

Comment: But my problems is if i change the extension i wont get the same availability when coding. I dont get the small help in DW

Comment: Then you need to make the decision at this time, what you need more. The removal of `.html` or the use of DW help.

Comment: okay, then I just change the extensions when im done with the file, if you can write as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible I'm afraid. For the `.htaccess` code to work, you will need to remove the `.html` from the code. Dreamweaver live isn't very good IMO and I would advise you install a tool like MAMP. Very easy to use.

You need to make the decision at this time on what you value more. The removal of `.html` off of your URLs or the use of Dreamweavers help function.

I'm sorry this answer isn't more helpful, but with any software, there is always downsides to it.